# R ggplot plot hourly data in most efficient way

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Trying to plot the below data in most **LOGICAL AND EFFICIENT WAY** to present it. I have already tried but none of it is can be called as efficient. I admit i dnt have good skills in plotting, most of my skills are limited with R data wrangling and writing functions. please if you have any better way to present, pls share.

| Date | emmm | hour | files | avg_download_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0000 | 2509 | 11.1744 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0015 | 2512 | 11.6200 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0030 | 2523 | 11.4025 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0045 | 2505 | 11.3429 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0100 | 2503 | 11.3004 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0115 | 2522 | 11.3926 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0130 | 2528 | 11.0665 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0145 | 2505 | 11.3090 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0200 | 2510 | 11.0400 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0215 | 2510 | 10.7739 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0230 | 2513 | 10.7199 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0245 | 2508 | 11.2412 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0300 | 2505 | 11.1671 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0315 | 2526 | 11.2823 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0330 | 2517 | 10.3066 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0345 | 2503 | 10.8194 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0400 | 2510 | 10.8888 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0415 | 2514 | 10.7601 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0430 | 2511 | 11.0823 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0445 | 2508 | 10.7962 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0500 | 2507 | 10.6736 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0515 | 2520 | 11.0360 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0530 | 2517 | 10.8877 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0545 | 2504 | 10.9927 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0600 | 2506 | 10.9125 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0615 | 2523 | 11.3744 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0630 | 2508 | 10.8896 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0645 | 2507 | 11.4358 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0700 | 2503 | 11.3354 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0715 | 2510 | 11.3844 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0730 | 2520 | 11.2636 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0745 | 2506 | 11.6731 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0800 | 2505 | 11.2959 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0815 | 2517 | 11.3446 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0830 | 2518 | 11.3282 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0845 | 2502 | 11.2678 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0900 | 2498 | 10.9907 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0915 | 2518 | 11.4335 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0930 | 2514 | 11.1982 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 0945 | 2500 | 11.4926 |
| 2023-02-05 | src14 | 1000 | 2504 | 11.0242 |

Trying to plot the above data, if you have any better idea to represent it in efficient way.

dput output -

```
> dput(pmstats_wh)
structure(list(Date = c("2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-05", "2023-02-05"), emmm = c("src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", "src14", 
"src14"), hour = c("0000", "0015", "0030", "0045", "0100", "0115", 
"0130", "0145", "0200", "0215", "0230", "0245", "0300", "0315", 
"0330", "0345", "0400", "0415", "0430", "0445", "0500", "0515", 
"0530", "0545", "0600", "0615", "0630", "0645", "0700", "0715", 
"0730", "0745", "0800", "0815", "0830", "0845", "0900", "0915", 
"0930", "0945", "1000", "1015", "1030", "1045", "1100", "1115", 
"1130", "1145", "1200", "1215", "1230", "1245", "1300", "1315", 
"1330", "1345", "1400", "1415", "1430", "1445", "1500", "1515", 
"1530", "1545", "1600", "1615", "1630", "1645", "1700", "1715", 
"1730", "1745", "1800", "1815", "1830", "1845", "1900", "1915", 
"1930", "1945", "2000", "2015", "2030", "2045", "2100", "2115", 
"2130", "2145", "2200", "2215", "2230", "2245", "2300", "2315", 
"2330"), files = c(2509L, 2512L, 2523L, 2505L, 2503L, 2522L, 
2528L, 2505L, 2510L, 2510L, 2513L, 2508L, 2505L, 2526L, 2517L, 
2503L, 2510L, 2514L, 2511L, 2508L, 2507L, 2520L, 2517L, 2504L, 
2506L, 2523L, 2508L, 2507L, 2503L, 2510L, 2520L, 2506L, 2505L, 
2517L, 2518L, 2502L, 2498L, 2518L, 2514L, 2500L, 2504L, 2514L, 
2524L, 2506L, 2501L, 2505L, 2514L, 2507L, 2503L, 2516L, 2519L, 
2508L, 2510L, 2514L, 2518L, 2510L, 2509L, 2508L, 2521L, 2509L, 
2509L, 2522L, 2510L, 2508L, 2510L, 2514L, 2519L, 2507L, 2507L, 
2531L, 2524L, 2514L, 2511L, 2522L, 2517L, 2508L, 2505L, 2519L, 
2516L, 2510L, 2507L, 2516L, 2513L, 2507L, 2507L, 2507L, 2519L, 
2507L, 2505L, 2506L, 2513L, 2508L, 2506L, 2518L, 2527L), avg_download_time = c(11.1743523316062, 
11.6199509023355, 11.4024507861012, 11.3428875582169, 11.3004328139566, 
11.3925852498017, 11.0665018459916, 11.308995342648, 11.0400464807437, 
10.7739243027888, 10.719850112747, 11.2412347155768, 11.1670592149035, 
11.2823370282396, 10.306648126076, 10.8193567718738, 10.8888379814077, 
10.7601431980907, 11.0822846143635, 10.796192185008, 10.6735806408722, 
11.0360052910053, 10.8877102370547, 10.9926850372737, 10.9124900239425, 
11.3744285903025, 10.8895733652313, 11.4358197048265, 11.3354108403249, 
11.3844355909695, 11.2636375661376, 11.6730845969673, 11.2959214903526, 
11.3446364719905, 11.3281969817315, 11.2677524646949, 10.9907325860689, 
11.433538522637, 11.1981636170777, 11.4926333333333, 11.024161341853, 
11.3491447891806, 11.3350699947174, 11.6433625964352, 11.3356857257097, 
11.7803393213573, 11.4575841951737, 11.4371626113549, 11.351591423625, 
11.8256293057764, 11.3967910546513, 11.9916400850611, 11.367802124834, 
11.7584062582869, 11.3772107492719, 12.1153386454183, 10.9719144413445, 
12.0148657628921, 11.4448631495438, 11.4261458748505, 11.4161950312209, 
11.4745968807824, 11.6785856573705, 11.753581871345, 11.9163545816733, 
11.5955780959958, 11.4409157072913, 11.9958316713203, 11.489044010105, 
11.8351047016989, 11.6366415742208, 12.0352161230443, 11.4454798884906, 
11.3649484536082, 11.8654019335187, 11.6714978734716, 11.6865069860279, 
11.7456265713908, 11.7357511923688, 11.7829482071713, 11.1552785533839, 
11.5564122946476, 11.4087412123624, 11.6988099986704, 11.4759805876878, 
11.7805677436511, 11.0163623130872, 11.8741922616673, 11.4924883566201, 
11.3075485501463, 11.2974665074944, 11.59528841042, 11.2385607874435, 
11.9739144823934, 11.8933320142461)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-95L))
```

Trying to represent the requirement like - : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Akqu.png

Comment: what kind of plot are you trying to make? what have you tried? what part is inefficient?

Comment: please share data with `dput()` so it is easier to help

Comment: What is the important information time? What comparisons do you want people viewing your graph to be able to make?

Comment: @Mike - attached.

Comment: @GregorThomas - trying to plot the no of files downloaded, with average download time per hour.

Comment: Cool, `ggplot(your_data, aes(x = files, y = avg_download_time)) + geom_point()`. Logical and efficient.

Comment: Though, I hear your objection already, `ggplot2` is slower to render than base plotting, so `with(your_data, plot(files, avg_download_time))` will be more efficient.

Comment: @GregorThomas - thanks, but this is very easy and simple, i am looking for more efficient and easy to represent.

Comment: What is the important information time? What comparisons do you want people viewing your graph to be able to make? This code is **very** efficient, so I don't know what you mean by "more efficient". It also perfectly demonstrates what you said was important above.

Comment: I'd suggest sketching a plot, showing a draft, talking in detail about what you want people to be able  or conclude for you graph... We don't know your data, what it really means, or how you are hoping to use it. We can't just build a graph for you that fits your needs.

Comment: @GregorThomas - added a sample, i am trying to present similar like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show *hourly* data. This requires grouping and summarising your data first. I would also advocate converting your dates and hours into a single date-time formatted column. If you want to show the number of files per hour as well as download speeds, you could add this as a text layer.

```r
library(tidyverse)

pmstats_wh %>%
  mutate(hour = as.numeric(substr(hour, 1, 2)),
         Date = as.Date(Date) + lubridate::hours(hour)) %>%
  group_by(Date, emmm) %>%
  summarise(download_time = sum(files * avg_download_time)/sum(files),
            files = sum(files)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, download_time, color = emmm)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = files), color = "black",
            nudge_y = 0.02, size = 3) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 hour", date_labels = "%b %d\n%H:%M") +
  labs(y = "Average download time", x = "Date / time",
       title = "Files download speed (with files per hour)") + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: thankyou man, for showing another approach. ... i didn't wanted to have it hourly, but it seems without it, becoming x-axis too stretched... trying now with hourly ... thanks ...